# Calculating edge count of non standard shape(?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So basically, I want to have a map of any size/proportion (locking it down to integers).

e.g.

$4 \times 4$

$\begin{matrix} 2 & 3 & 3 & 2\\ 3 &4 &4 &3\\ 3 & 4& 4& 3\\2& 3& 3& 2\end{matrix}$

The number represents the amount of edges it will have, basically every single point on the map has connection (to and from) every point that it is next to, with exclusion of the diagnoal points. So the ones in the corner will always have only $2$ edges (four total since the edges it is connected to also have one going back to it). So in this case $4\times4$ has $48$ edges (atleast in my world) I am looking for a good method that will allow me to quickly calculate the count of edges of any map of this type e.g.

$3\times5$ or $10000\times1235$ or whatever the size might be.

Comment: You need to edit your post to clarify what exactly you are asking. What do you mean by "*map*"? How do the numbers 2 3 3 2 correspond to a map? Some kind of picture would be helpful.

Comment: The number on the map represents the amount of edges there are from the specific point (for your information) What I am going to be given is simply dimensions of the map.

Comment: For rectangular grids the answer is straightforward - An $a\times b$ grid will have $4ab -2(a+b)$ links under your definition. Did you have more complicated shapes in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

You know there are always four corners, which will contribute $2 \times 4 = 8$ edges to the total.

Can you count the number of interior points? Those will contribute $4$ edges each.

How many edge points that aren't corners? What do they contribute?

When you add these three totals,  do you get the answer you expect? For the $2 \times 2$ shape do you want  $4$ or $8$?

(There are other ways to answer your question. I chose one suggested by the picture you drew.)